# Backref in list?

Tags: python, regex, backreference

I'm trying to make a regex that matches strings in which the characters are arranged alphabetically, e.g. "ab", but not "ba". Here's my attempt: `(.)[\1-z]`. It captures the first character and uses that for the beginning of the range in the list. However, in the `[]`, `\1` means `U+0001`, so it matches any two characters:

```py
>>> re.search("(.)[\1-z]", "ab")
<re.Match object; span=(0, 2), match='ab'>
>>> re.search("(.)[\1-z]", "ba")
<re.Match object; span=(0, 2), match='ba'>
```

How can I backref a captured character in a character list?

Comment: Backreferences inside character classes don't work. In some engines it might try to convert `\1` to an octal `\100`

Comment: You can't do this. Capture groups can only be referenced to match them literally against text, not as part of character classes.

Comment: Also, regex can't count or do math natively.

Answer (score 2):

You'll have to spell it out completely, i.e `a*b*c*d*.....`.

Here is how you could do that:

```
regex = "(?=.)" + "*".join(map(chr, range(97, 123))) + "*"
s = "afkdiolsieyrnbsgdysoepkzavfz"
print(re.findall(regex, s))
```

Comment: cool! Your answer is so much more elegant than mine.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you could create a long regex which just checks each letter to make sure it's not succeeded by a letter of lower lexicographic rank. For example:

```
^
  (?=.{2,}) # assert length of two or more?
  (?:a(?=.*))*
  (?:b(?=.*[^a].*))*
  (?:c(?=.*[^a-b].*))*
  (?:d(?=.*[^a-c].*))*
  # add in the rest...
$
```

Here would be a [link](https://regex101.com/r/dmnHZg/1) to a working example:

[image]